# Extract the max value of a set of pixels, from a vector list

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, numpy-ndarray

Im working on python and I need to extract the max or min values from a set of specific pixels on a image. lets say my image is a 40 by 40 image. I have a list with some given vector coordinates example: `vectorlist=[[10,15],[13,14],[15,23]]`. I need to extract the pixel values of those vectors in the list and calculate the min and max. I am looking for some fast way to do it, because a FOR loop is to slow.

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,len(vectorlist)):
       a.append(image[vectorlist[i][0],vectorlist[i][1]])
max1=max(a)
min1=min(a)
```

if there is faster way to do it, that would be great!

thanks!

Comment: If the `for` loop in your example is mandatory for building your array, you can use it to get the max and min values, with something like `if (max1 is None or max1 > image[vectorlist[i][0],vectorlist[i][1]]):...` and `if (min1 is None or min1 < image[vectorlist[i][0],vectorlist[i][1]]):...`

Comment: I'm still a Python noob, but I think you want *"fancy indexing"*.... https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/02.07-fancy-indexing.html Or maybe a *"masked array"*... https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/maskedarray.generic.html

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Mark that creating a mask array is probably a good idea because you can reuse this mask for other operations on this array.

```
import numpy as np
#create test data with random but reproducible data
np.random.seed(54321)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 255, (40, 40), dtype = "uint8")

vectorlist = [[10, 15], [13, 14], [15, 23]]
#extracting rows and columns of the vectorlist
rows, cols = zip(*vectorlist)
#create mask at points defined by vectorlist 
mask = np.zeros(arr.shape, dtype = bool)
mask[rows, cols] = True
print(arr[mask])
#output
#[ 49 245 197]
print(np.max(arr[mask]))
#245
print(np.min(arr[mask]))
#49
```

Please note that the indexing starts at 0, not 1 - your question is not clear, if this is taken into consideration by your `vectorlist`. And make sure that in your list the first value represents the row. If not, just switch `rows` and `cols` in the script, when retrieving these values from the `zip` object.

Comment: this completely eliminates use of `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

I am an absolute beginner on Python, but it seems my comment was wrong, but I'll *"man up"* and admit it and say how I worked it out and maybe someone will know why. Before anyone says it's not an answer, it is, because it does improve on the original code (in function `loop()`) by introducing the improved `loop2()` function:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3
import numpy as np

# Generate an array 40x40 of random integers <100
image=np.random.randint(100,size=(40,40))

# List of pixels we like
vectorlist=[[0,0],[1,1],[1,0],[39,39]]

# Boolean mask of elements we like
mask=np.reshape(np.zeros(1600,dtype=bool),(40,40))
mask[0,0]=mask[1,1]=mask[1,0]=mask[39,39]=True

# OP's suggested method
def loop():
   a=[]
   for i in range(0,len(vectorlist)):
      a.append(image[vectorlist[i][0],vectorlist[i][1]])
   mi=min(a)
   ma=max(a)
   return(mi,ma)

# Slight improvement on OP's method
def loop2():
   # Don't add a bunch of items to a list we don't need
   mi=ma=image[vectorlist[0][0],vectorlist[0][1]]
   for i in range(1,len(vectorlist)):
      this=image[vectorlist[i][0],vectorlist[i][1]]
      if this>ma:
          ma=this
      elif this<mi:
          mi=this
   return (mi,ma)

# My very own slow method using a masked array
def masked():
   selpix=image[mask]
   mi=np.amin(selpix)
   ma=np.amax(selpix)
   return (mi,ma)

print(loop())
print(loop2())
print(masked())
```

**Sample Output**

```
(22, 91)
(22, 91)
(22, 91)
```

I pasted all the above into `IPython` and then ran the following timing tests:

```
In [178]: %timeit loop()
1.96 µs ± 6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [179]: %timeit loop2()
1.4 µs ± 2.21 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

In [180]: %timeit masked()
4.64 µs ± 32.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Disappointed of Cheltenham :-)